# Same column in dynamic object list has string as well as integer

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm receiving a json doc from 3rd party which when deserialized has a dynamic object list in following format

```
period       key      value
"2013-3"     0   5
"2013-4"     1   6
.
.
.
"2013-10"    5   15
"2013-11"    mykey1   25
"2013-12"    mykey3   6
```

On this when I try to run a linq query I get an error..  System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

This goes away if I keep only string or int values in key column..

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Example linq query::

```
data.Where(w => w.key  == "mykey1").Select(s => s.value).ToArray();
```

Example : http://rextester.com/OMRG78541

Comment: what is your linq query?

Comment: updated with example linq query

Comment: As long as your `key` property is a `string`, and not an `int`, then the fact that there are two different "types" is inconsequential. The exception that you provided makes it sound like something else is going on, but you haven't provided enough information for that.

Comment: I have a json, I deserialize it to dynamic object and am working on it.. so key property would probably be dynamic ..

Comment: @MaksimSimkin krillgar http://rextester.com/OMRG78541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using dynamic object you need to cast the key in order to validate the predicate in your lambda expression. That is because even though you are using dynamic the underlying object is a JValue which wont allow for the `==` between the string and JValue

```
data.Where(w => (string)w.key == "mykey1").Select(s => s.value).ToArray();
```

Given the sample code

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "[{\"period\":\"2013-3\",\"key\":1,\"val\":18148},{\"period\":\"2013-3\",\"key\":\"totalinteractions\",\"val\":95862},{\"period\":\"2013-3\",\"key\":\"totalusers\",\"val\":160389},{\"period\":\"2013-4\",\"key\":\">10\",\"val\":69915}]";
            var inputdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(json);
            var list = inputdata.Where(w => (string)w.key == "totalusers").Select(s => s.val).ToArray();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above would result in

```
160389
```